# Filter table to show only records which apply to all conditions

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have a table and I want to return all the products which have not been classified as RANGED during that campaign period.
So if I filtered on Campaign A it will only return the products that have never ever been ranged so it will only return Grapes.

So it will look at each filtered row and for each product check whether the range is equal to NO

```
Campaign              Product       Range          
A                      Apple         YES            
A                      Banana        NO
A                      Banana        NO
A                      Banana        YES
A                      Grapes        NO
A                      Grapes        NO
```

How would I go about creating such table using DAX?

I have tried using filter but this will return the rows which have the range `NO` rather than returning only the products for that specific campaign where every row of that product has not been ranged.

**Current Output:**

```
Banana
Grapes
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Grapes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Table 2 = 
VAR t =
    ADDCOLUMNS(
    SUMMARIZE('Table', 'Table'[Campaign], 'Table'[Product]),
    "@x", CALCULATE(COUNT('Table'[Range]), 'Table'[Range] = "Yes"
        )
    )

RETURN SELECTCOLUMNS( FILTER(t, [@x] = BLANK()), "Product", 'Table'[Product])
```

[image]